# How to set up FrameLayout to the far right side in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, xml

I would like the Search Button at the far right side in HorizontalScrollView.
I tried to use android:layout_alignParentRight="true" ,
 but it didn't work
How Can I do?
thanks a lot

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpXb0.png)

My XML Code：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/folderPath_horizontalScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/folder_path_scrollbar_thumb"
android:splitMotionEvents="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/folderPath_folder_path"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/blue_B500"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_search"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/actionbar_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
        android:background="?actionBarItemBackground">

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/divider_line" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Common_003"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't as there is no "far right" to `HorizontalScrollView`.

`HorizontalScrollView` have infinite width so it can not have far right.

Move your search ImageView outside the `HorizontalScrollView` within RelativeLayout then you can do `layout_alignParentRight`.